# What to resolve the dependencies between jemalloc and pthread in cmake?

Tags: pthreads, cmake

I have a project that depends on `jemalloc` as an external library. `jemalloc` depends on `pthread` in turn. In cmake, how can I specify the dependency between these two libraries?

So far I tried:

1. `target_link_libraries(jemalloc pthread)` which doesn't work because `jemalloc` is an external library
2. `target_link_libraries(current_library jemalloc pthread)` which works, but it's inconvenient to specify `pthread` after `jemalloc` in all libraries where `jemalloc` is used. I also need to add `jemalloc pthread` for every executable and test.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but from my reading of the manual, you should be able to set `IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES` and/or `IMPORTED_LINK_DEPENDENT_LIBRARIES` on jemalloc to specify the dependency.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Would you like to change your comment to an answer so I can select it as the best response to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the imported library's [`IMPORTED_LINK_DEPENDENT_LIBRARIES`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aIMPORTED_LINK_DEPENDENT_LIBRARIES) and/or [`IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aIMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES) properties to specify the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to "properly" specify a dependency between two external libraries like this.

The best you can probably do is something like `find_library` for each, and with the results (assuming they're both found correctly) `set` a single variable representing both libraries.

So, something like:

```
find_library(JemallocLib jemalloc)
find_library(PthreadLib pthread)
set(JemallocLibs ${JemallocLib} ${PthreadLib})
```

Then you can just do e.g.

```
target_link_libraries(MyLib ${JemallocLibs})
target_link_libraries(MyExe MyLib)  # automatically links jemalloc and pthread too
```